How do I automatically extract data from another sheet with criteria?
I have a main sheet Sheet 1 where I input data every day.

Each row contains the following 3 columns: Date, Cashier Name, Cashier Short Amount.
The Date column contains merged rows and each row in a merged group is understood to share the same Date as the first row in that group
Included Cashier Names vary by Date and the rows within a particular Date are unsorted.

I have a 2nd sheet Sheet 2 to summarize each staff's data.

Each row represents a unique Date
Each unique Cashier Name is in 2nd and subsequent columns with their totals for each date (as applicable) in the rows below.

I do not know the right formula for Google Sheets to automatically detect each staff's name in the 1st Sheet and assign the values according to their columns in the 2nd Sheet. I tried searching for the right formula on Google and YouTube but couldn't find any.
Please refer to the tables and images below:

Example Sheet 1



1
DATE 
CASHIER NAME
CASHIER SHORT AMOUNT




2
Jan 1
ALICE
10.00


3

BONNIE
25.00


4

CLARK
9.25


5

DAVID
1.13


6
Jan 2
EVE
70.00


7

FELICIA
14.75


8

ALICE
0.20


9

GEORGE
0.00


10
Jan 3
DAVID
4.10


11

EVE
3.20


12

FELICIA
11.14


13

GEORGE
0.99


14
Jan 4
BONNIE
25.67


15

CLARK
13.00


16

DAVID
18.92


17

EVE
0.00



Example Sheet 2



1
DATE 
ALICE
BONNIE
CLARK
DAVID
EVE
FELICIA
GEORGE




2
Jan 1
10.00
25.00
9.25
1.13





3
Jan 2
0.20



70.00
14.75
0.00


4
Jan 3



4.10
3.20
11.14
0.99


5
Jan 4

25.67
13.00
18.92
0.00






To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of winging it from screenshots), the recommended method is to create a markdown table. Use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Additionally you can also share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing

That is simple to do with query(), provided that you unmerge the cells in column A so that dates appear on every row. The formula to pivot the data would then be like this:
=query(A1:C, "select Col1, sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2" , 1)

To hide repeated dates in the unmerged cells in column A, use conditional formatting to set text color white when the value in a cell equals the value in the cell above.
If you need keep the cells merged for some reason, you can use the fillDown_ pattern, like this:
=let( 
  fillDown_, lambda(a, let(r,max(bycol(a,lambda(l,index(ifna(xmatch("?*",to_text(l),2,-1)))))),s,sequence(r),array_constrain(bycol(a,lambda(v,map(s,lambda(i,index(xlookup(i,s/(v<>""),v,,-1)))))),r,columns(a)))), 

  query(filldown_(A1:D), "select Col1, sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2" , 1) 
)

The query statement is the same in both alternatives.
See query() and Haluk's sample spreadsheet.

QUERY with SCAN
=QUERY({scan(,A:A, LAMBDA(a,v, IF(LEN(v),v,a))),A:C},
   "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col4) Where Col3 is not Null
    GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col3",1)


SCAN is used to add a column that includes the missing dates
QUERY does the aggregation and pivot's the results

IF  INDEX  LAMBDA  LEN  LET  QUERY  SUM

Source Data




A
B
C




1
DATE
CASHIER NAME
CASHIER SHORT AMOUNT


2
Jan 1
ALICE
10.00


3

BONNIE
25.00


4

CLARK
9.25


5

DAVID
1.13


6
Jan 2
EVE
70.00


7

FELICIA
14.75


8

ALICE
0.20


9

GEORGE
0.00


10
Jan 3
DAVID
4.10


11

EVE
3.20


12

FELICIA
11.14


13

GEORGE
0.99


14
Jan 4
BONNIE
25.67


15

CLARK
13.00


16

DAVID
18.92


17

EVE
0.00




Ty. Typo fixed.

I avoid using merged cells whenever possible, because they tend to cause problems.
But, if you must use the merged cells then you may use the formula below to create the table;
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TEXT(IF(B2:B="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1)),"mmm dd"), B2:C},"Select Col1, Sum(Col3) Where Col2 Is Not Null Group By Col1 Pivot Col2 Label Col1 'DATE'",0))

A sample sheet is also added in the link below, for anyone willing to supply a better alternative using the data.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mCDkn4HxjFmlwJ9E3WsC22ESTQ5J3RzMzvBxA6tBbLI/edit?usp=sharing
.

.
Another option is to use the SCAN function for the source table of the QUERY function;
=QUERY({SCAN("",A2:A,LAMBDA(acc,xVal,IF(ISBLANK(xVal),acc,xVal))), B2:C},"Select Col1, Sum(Col3) Where Col2 Is Not Null Group By Col1 Pivot Col2 Label Col1 'DATE'",0)

